# On Spark's RDD's take and takeOrdered methods

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a bit confused on how Spark's rdd.take(n) and rdd.takeOrdered(n) works. Can someone explain to me these two methods with some examples? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you explain what exactly you find confusing. Is it implementation itself or just a way how to use these? Or maybe something else?

Comment: @zero323 Basically, the way how to use these. It's in the code of my colleague, and I'm trying to understand his code, but being new to Scala / Spark, I'm having a hard time. He's out and can't ask him at this time.

Answer (score 10):

In order to explain how ordering works we create an RDD with integers from 0 to 99:

```
val myRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq.range(0, 100))
```

We can now perform:

```
myRdd.take(5)
```

Which will extract the first 5 elements of the RDD and we will obtain an Array[Int] containig the first 5 integers of myRDD: '0 1 2 3 4 5' (with no ordering function, just the first 5 elements in the first 5 position)

The takeOrdered(5) operation works in a similar way: it will extract the first 5 elements of the RDD as an Array[Int] but we have to opportunity to specify the ordering criteria:

```
myRdd.takeOrdered(5)( Ordering[Int].reverse)
```

Will extract the first 5 elements according to specified ordering. In our case the result will be: '99 98 97 96 95'

If you have a more complex data structure in your RDD you may want to perform your own ordering function with the operation:

```
myRdd.takeOrdered(5)( Ordering[Int].reverse.on { x => ??? })
```

Which will extract the first 5 elements of your RDD as an Array[Int] according to your custom ordering function.